# Simple Angular js Not Working on Plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

Can you please take a look at [This Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/U26qWHFVmUtKpxgvIf1p?p=preview) and let me know why it is not working?

here is the code I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0-alpha.31" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
      <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and in `script.js`:

```
var FirstController = function($scope){
    $scope.msg = "This Must Work!";
};
```

Comment: I'm getting 404 for https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js

Comment: That's not angular2 sintaxis, it's angular1's. I recommend you the [5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to use angular or angular 2? Angular 2 is in beta right now and not the commonly used version.

In case of angular 1, there are some small mistakes.

First of all, you didn't declare the app in your javascript. To do this you should write something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

Then, you used the `ng-app` directive, but didn't provide a value for it. It should be the same value as the 'module' you made previously (`myApp` in this case).

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Next, to be able to use a controller in your app, you have to 'attach' it to your app. Otherwise, angular doesn't know it's existence. We do this like so:

```
myApp.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'This Must Work!';
}]);
```

I also used the angular CDN for this example.

And a working [Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FZo8eVn4bLESVYACSPZt)

Comment: Thanks Wout, but in this step I do not want to create a Module. I am following a tutorial from Pluralsight and this is working on the video tutorial!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial (I have an account on that website from work)

Answer (score 2):

The angular file (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js) you are linking to is not valid. So angular never loads.

Comment: Thanks potatopeelings, but where to get the angular 2 then? and why it is not workimg on plunker?

Comment: Angular 2  - Alpha 31, you can link to it from here https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.js. You need to do a bit more to have 2.0 set up in the plunkr. The 5 min quickstart @Eric Martinez linked to is a good place to get started with setting up 2.0. 

However do verify that it is indeed angular 2 being used in the tutorial, the script is very un2.0 like.

Answer (score 1):

The angular reference that you are using is not valid. I tweaked the code with a valid reference to angular and it works fine. Also, you are not creating the controller properly, first you should create a module and then add a controller to it. 
This is what the "script.js" file should look like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "This Must Work!";
});
```

And this is what the updated html with valid angular reference looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src= "script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstController">  
       <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice I also added ng-app="myApp" to give  reference to the module created. Hope this helps.